# Reading a File and processing elements having same ID

Tags: python

So I want to process the sample file given below line by line and process all the records having same ID (1,2,3,7 in the file below) at once and then after processing move on to the next ID. I have written some code which reads in this file once, read the first id, store it in a variable and then close the file. After this I open the file again and go after processing it line by line.

```
testprogdata.csv

10,xyz,abx
10,mno,mnc
10,mnp,klo
10,apl,lko
2,pol,okl
3,jkl,mlp
3,jsd,sdf
3,fds,lpo
7,iko,opi
```

Python Program to read the above file:

```
file=open('testprogdata.csv')
for line in file:
    sL=line.split(',')
    en=sL[0]
    break
file.close()

file=open('testprogdata.csv')

for line in file:
    sL=line.split(',')
    x=sL[0]
    if(x==en):
        print x //Do something processing 
    else:
        #process(x)
        en=x
        print "-----------"
        print x


Output

10
10
10
10
----------
2
----------
3
3
3
----------
7
```

Now I am not comfortable with the code that I have written as it seems to be a bad programming pattern for a simple problem. What is the good way of accomplishing the above very common pattern? Even if I use hashing I will be doing the same above.

Comment: How big is your file? Would you be comfortable to read the entire content and then process it?

Comment: The file has ids in the ascending order?

Comment: @Abhijit Thanks! I just wanted to know in both the scenarios 1) When the file is too big and I want to read it line by line & also 2) When it can fit in the memory at once (small file). As I thought this should be a very common pattern that many programmers irrespective of language might have encountered.

Comment: @NigelTufnel Thanks! Nope it is all random. Edited the question above with random numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pythonic way would be to use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby), and a [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.reader#csv.reader):

```
import csv
import itertools

def process(stuff):
    print ' '.join(stuff)

with open("values.csv") as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f)
    for idnum, group in itertools.groupby(rd, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        print "processing ID {}".format(idnum)
        for item in group:
            process(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read all lines with the same id, process and repeat again:

```
f=open('testprogdata.csv', "r")
id_to_process = 1
lines_to_process = []

while True:
   raw_line = f.readline()

   # check whether we're at eof       
   if not raw_line:
        break

   # get line
   line = raw_line.rstrip().split(",")
   id = line[0]

   # same id
   if id == id_to_process:
       lines_to_process.append(line)

   # a new id is comming
   else:
       # do something with your lines
       foobar(lines_to_process)

       # now proceed with next id
       id_to_process = id
       lines_to_process = [line]

f.close()
```

But note: the code requires a grouped list of lines. Otherwise it makes not sense to processs them that way.